# How to use Selenium to click on a link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click a link using Selenium with Python. The text is "104" in the following html code:

```
<a class="_2x4v" href="/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=2411812215520941&amp;av=200007162833925" rel="ignore" role="button">1045
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="_1g5v">
    <span data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-uri="/ufi/reaction/tooltip/?ft_ent_identifier=2411812215520941&amp;av=200007162833925">104</span>
  </span>
  <span class="_4arz">
    <span data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-uri="/ufi/reaction/tooltip/?ft_ent_identifier=2411812215520941&amp;av=200007162833925">104</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="104"]').click()
```

But I received an error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[text()="104"]"}
```

What should I do?

Comment: There are 2 same span nodes with text `"104"`... Is it typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link has no child text node `"104"` - it's child text node of span. You can try below options to match required link:

```
//a[span="104"]
```

or

```
//a[.//text()="104"]
```

or

```
//a[.//span[text()="104"]]
```

...